# Search multiple word in regex

Tags: regex

I have a list of word and I want to find them in a string (all of them).
Words can be found anywhere in the string without any order.
For example :

```
str = "word2 bla bla word2 word1 word3 blabla word4" 
wordList = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]
if regex(str):
   print "it worked !"
else:
   print "it didn't work !"
```

The list will change in number and in content.
It's for configuring an other program(pentaho), so I cannot really write code around like that.

If it's possible in wanna add a list a optionnally words, and if one of them is part of the string, it's return true.

I don't know if the second part is possible in 1 regex, but if you could help me with the first one.

Comment: Do all words need to match, or any words?

Comment: When do you want "*it worked !*" printed? When *all* the words are found in the string, or when at least one is found? Also, which language/platform are you using the regex in?

Comment: I add some precisions, yes, all the words have to match for the first part, otherwise it's false.

Comment: I can find a word ^.*(wordX)+.*$, or all of them, but I cannot find out how to have them without any predefined order

Comment: To express AND conditions in regex, you use lookeaheads like `^(?=.*word1)(?=.*word2)` etc.

Comment: I manage to create it, the first version with what you said, the second with a (?=.*optionalWord1|optionalWord2|...)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this would be to not use regex:

```
if all(word in str for word in wordList):
  print "it worked!"
else:
  print "it didn't work!"
```